# Strange behavior of Windows Forms combobox control

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, combobox

I am developing a small desktop app, and there are several drop-down lists (combobox-es) on my form. I populate a list of strings, which will be used as data source for all of them. Here is example from my Form.cs class:

```
List<string> datasource = new List<string>();
datasource.Add("string 1");
datasource.Add("string 2");
```

Then I set this list as a data source to several comboboxes:

```
 cmbDataType1.DataSource = datasource;
 cmbDataType2.DataSource = datasource;
```

This all happens in same method, which is called from the Form constructor.
Here is the strange part: after I change a selected value in one of them, the same value will be set in the other one. There are no `SelectedIndexChange` events set. I have messed up somewhere, but I cant put my finger where...

Comment: Here is [a link to a blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2007/09/19/binding-multiple-comboboxes-to-the-same-datasource.aspx) that talks about this some.  It's about vb.net, but the description of the behavior should be the same either way.

Comment: It really clarified some things, thanks man.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The behavior that you see is by design. When you bind the same object as the data source for multiple controls, all the controls share the same binding source.

If you explicitly assign a new binding source to each control, even while using the same data source, all controls will be unbound and will act independent of each other:

```
cmbDataType1.DataSource = new BindingSource(datasource, "");
cmbDataType2.DataSource = new BindingSource(datasource, "");
```

Answer (score 4):

You should set a new [BindingContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingcontext.aspx) for the control before binding the dataSource the next time:

```
cmbDataType1.BindingContext = new BindingContext();
cmbDataType1.DataSource = datasource;

cmbDataType2.BindingContext = new BindingContext();
cmbDataType2.DataSource = datasource;
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you are binding to the same exact `datasource` that is the expected behavior. You will want to change your binding to be a `OneWay` binding or use different objects if you don't want the selecteditem to change.

Comment: It's still curious though.  The data source is a list of strings.  How does combobox 2 know that the selected index changed in combobox 1?  There is no way to store that info in a list.

Comment: That's just the magic of binding to a data source. Changing the index in combobox1 is what told the datasource to move its internal pointer which in turn triggers the change in combobox2.

Comment: I'm just trying to workout the implementation for my own curiosity... so I imagine that they wrap the list in a data source structure with the bookeeping data needed, things like "current item".  How would both comboboxes have a reference to the same wrapper?  I assume they would both create one when their respective `DataSource` properties were set, meaning the communication wouldn't work.  Interesting...