# ComboBox behaving in a not expected way

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, windows

I have two comboboxes which I populate using my `GetAllCities()` method in the `CtrlMap`.

My idea is, whenever I select another city on the `ddFrom` it should databind all the cities to `ddTo` (and later on remove the exact same selected, so user won't be able to select same city as point From and To).

However, Whenever I select something on `ddFrom`, `ddTo` populates (as it should), but `SelectedIndex` gets the same as the `ddFrom`. Same goes in the opposite way. If I select a city, lets say `New York` on `ddTo` it is also selected on `ddFrom`.

In the `GUINewBooking.Designer.cs` there's only this event handler registered: `this.ddFrom.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.ddFrom_SelectedIndexChanged);`

`ddTo` has no event handler registered. Any ideas?

```
public partial class GUINewBooking : Form
{
    private CtrlMap ctrlMap;

    public GUINewBooking()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ctrlMap = new CtrlMap();

        ddFrom.DataSource = ctrlMap.GetAllCities();
        ddFrom.DisplayMember = "name";
    }

    private void ddFrom_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ddTo.DataSource = ctrlMap.GetAllCities();
        ddTo.DisplayMember = "name";
    }
}
```

Comment: The answer lies in the code of GetAllCities. Please show it

Comment: Actually it does not. `GetAllCities()` just returns a List. I found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8720683/strange-behavior-of-windows-forms-combobox-control?rq=1

Comment: However if GetAllCities returns the same object instance then the behavior is exactly the one you get.

Comment: @Nikola it kind of is, seems that `GetAllCities` returns every time the same instance

Comment: @Steve, @Guru Stron it does return the same thing every time, however both should not behave exactly the same (selecting `A` on `ddTo` making `A` selected on `ddFrom`, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer can be found [Strange behavior of Windows Forms combobox control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8720683/strange-behavior-of-windows-forms-combobox-control?lq=1)

Each combobox `DataSource` property should be assigned to a different `BindingSource` object.

Example:

```
cmbDataType1.DataSource = new BindingSource(datasource, "");
cmbDataType2.DataSource = new BindingSource(datasource, "");
```

Or in my particular case:

```
ddFrom.DataSource = new BindingSource(ctrlMap.GetAllCities(), "");
ddTo.DataSource = new BindingSource(ctrlMap.GetAllCities(), "");
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because you are using the same data source. You might need to

```
private void ddFrom_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CtrlMap ctrlMapTo = new CtrlMap();
    ddTo.DataSource = ctrlMap2.GetAllCities();
    ddTo.DisplayMember = "name";
}
```